# Please help me to remove a blank line from the file

Tags: c, file, removing-whitespace

```
char temp[100];
FILE *fptr;
fptr=fopen("files.txt","w");
for(int i=0;i<n*7;i++)
{
    fgets(temp,100,stdin);
    // fputs(temp,fptr);
    fprintf(fptr,"%s",temp);
}
fclose(fptr);
```

This is my code to take input from user and simultaneously write it in the file. The error is that I am getting a blank line at the start of the file which I don't want. Don't bother in the n*7 , it is because of taking that many inputs. Please help.

Comment: `if (fgets (temp,100,stdin) && *temp != '\n') { /* now right it to the file */ }`. You can use `temp[0]` instead of `*temp` if you are more comfortable with indexes.

Comment: Thankyou so much, you are genius. Do you have any explanation that why was the blank line appearing without any reason?

Comment: In a file each line ends with the `'\n'` character. `fgets()` will read each line (including the `'\n'` character) storing everything in `temp` (as long as the line fits). When you encounter a blank line in input, `fgets()` simply reads and stores the `'\n'` character in `temp`. So to check if a line is blank (empty), you just check if the first character in `temp` is the `'\n'` character. If it is, you know that line was empty, so you skip writing it out to the file. The `*temp != '\n'` check just says "What `fgets()` stored was not just the `'\n'` character."